# Building native module to install via npm but unable to link android module

Tags: android, react-native

I'm working on creating an npm module for use in react native that uses native java/ objective c libraries and I'm running into some trouble with android.

I'm following the react native documentation for creating native modules here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-setup

Those steps are straight forward and I'm able to get my native code in place, run `npm pack` in the root directory of the module, `npm install /path/to/module/package-0.1.0.tgz` in the root directory of my project, `cd ios && pod install` and have the native ios module linked, running fine and accessible via NativeModule.

I start running into problems on the android side because the module doesn't appear with the rest of the packages, as far as I know everything should auto link and I shouldnt need any custom setup but non the less I've tried adding `include ':custom-package'` to `settings.gradle`, and even adding `packages.add(new CustomPackage());` to `MainApplication.java` but of course it's unable to resolve my CustomPackage. Is there something I'm missing? Seems odd that android isnt working considering I'm using the built in `create-react-native-library` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well not sure what I did wrong the first few times when I tried the above process but I tried again from scratch using the `create-react-native-library` and it worked perfectly, android module got auto linked and life is good again.